# Item deletion using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Am having a problem with my jquery

i want to delete some products

but the only problem am getting, the deletion works only on first items even if i click the last item

Lets say i want to delete `<p>INFO 20002</p>` it will delete  `<p>INFO 2000</p>`

i want to be able to delete any item i want

```
<script>
   function callB() {
    
    $("#button1").click(function(event) {
        Execute();
    });
   
    function Execute() {
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/file.aspx',
            data: {
                'custId': $("input[name='custId']").val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                    
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    };
   }
   
   $(document).ready(function() {
    callB();
   });
</script>



<div>
<p>INFO 2000</p>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Erase this">
 <input type="hidden" name="custId" value="348700">
</div>

<div>
<p>INFO 20001</p>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Erase this">
<input type="hidden" name="custId" value="4443487">
</div>

<div>
<p>INFO 20002</p>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Erase this">
<input type="hidden" name="custId" value="8883487">
</div>

<div>
<p>INFO 20003</p>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Erase this">
<input type="hidden" name="custId" value="1113487">
</div>
```

Comment: All your buttons have the same id. It's supposed to be unique though. Here's the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/k1a3ufb8/

Comment: thanks  Mr.Chris  this has worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Because all your button have same `ids` i.e. `button1` and when you click any button your function `Execute();` executed and inside your ajax data you are sending data with `$("input[name='custId']").val()` means it will always give you the value of first occurrence and that is why when clicking any button because all your buttons have same ids the `Execute()` function executed and your first item deleted.So when you click any button send that clicked button value your problem will be solved. Also please try to give the `id` value `unique`.

```
$("[type=button]").on('click', function() {
     var custId = $(this).closest('div').find('[name=custId]').val();
     Execute(custId);
});

function Execute(custId) {
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax/file.aspx',
        data: {
            'custId': custId
        },
        success: function(response) {
                
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input buttons need to have unique id attributes (or no ids at all, in this case).

Give all of them the same class-name.

```
<input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="Erase this" />
```

Put the customer id into the 'button' element, instead of its own hidden input.

```
<input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="Erase this" data-custid="348700" />
```

Then update your jquery selector for the button click event, and refer to that class-name.

```
$('input.deleteButton').on('click', function(event) {

  var $button = $(this);
  // USE THE jQUERY OBJECT'S .data() METHOD TO GET THE BUTTON's CUST-ID
  // var customerId = $button.data('custid');
  Execute($button);

});
```

Then, on the 'success' of the ajax request, refer to the '$button' object, and remove its `<div>` parent.

```
$button.closest('div').remove();
```